# Galaxy S7 going offline in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, offline, samsung-galaxy

I had previously used a Samsung Galaxy S5 for many years with Android Studio, without an issue.  However, I recently switched to a Galaxy S7 and when I connect it to my PC it will be available in Android Studio for when I run\debug. Then, it goes offline.

I have tried turning the USB debugging feature off and on again, but it didn't work. If you have any suggestions to how I could resolve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using your samsung to test your apps?

Comment: Try updating your sdk according to the android os version used in the mobile to keep it online.

Comment: Did you try ‘adb kill-server‘?

Comment: Actually ended up being a cable issue.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try installing Samsung OEM usb driver.
2. When connected to PC, check your phone to accept the connection request.